# Configurar subdominios Apache en máquina Red Hat dentro de AWS

Tags: apache, aws, fedora

Busco configurar unos subdominios:

```
subdominio1.dominio.com (document root: www/html/subdominio1)
subdominio2.dominio.com (document root: www/html/subdominio2)
```

En un Apache instalado dentro de un **Red Hat** en **AWS:**

1. Realizo la configuracion de los `VirtualHost` con su `serverAlias` cada uno.
2. Reinicio el servidor y desde el navegador digito la URL del dominio, la cual me lleva al contenido del primer `VirtualHost`.
3. Al digitar en la URL `subdominio1.dominio.com` me devuelve que no puede acceder al sitio o encontrar la IP asociada al subdominio.

Como la máquina está en **AWS** no sé si debo realizar alguna configuracion adicional en **AWS Manager**.

Vi el siguiente [video](https://hostingjournalist.com/video/aws-knowledge-center-videos-how-do-i-create-a-sub-domain-with-aws-route-53/), pero no sé si es necesario crear esas zonas para permitir los subdominios (no tengo acceso al **Manager de AWS**).

La configuracion de los `VirtualHost` la realice similar a la del siguiente ejemplo en [Digital Ocean](https://ed.team/blog/como-crear-subdominios-en-apache-con-digital-ocean) sin la parte de configuracion del Manager de **Digital Ocean**, lo cual supongo similar a **AWS**.

Answer (score 0):

El problema que comentas no parece ser del servidor si no que falta definir el otro subdominio en la configuración del DNS de tu dominio, agrega una entrada nueva en la consola de administración de tu DNS para subdominio2 con un registro de tipo A apuntando a la misma dirección de subdominio1, cuando la petición llegue al servidor apache se encargará de realizar el enrutamiento al directorio correspondiente.